# Why was Robert Carlyle uncredited in "Yesterday"?

Tags: credits, yesterday

Robert Carlyle played a significant role in the film "Yesterday", but he doesn't appear in the credits.

That's obviously not an accidental oversight, so why would it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [vanityfair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/06/yesterday-movie-beatles-ed-sheeran-questions):

> Toward the final act, Jack travels to a faraway house (shot on Shingle
>   Street in Suffolk) to visit an old man. It turns out to be John
>   Lennon, who, in this alternate timeline, became an old man living a
>   modest, peaceful life. He’s played by an uncredited actor, though
>   sleuths have deduced that the man in question is frequent Danny Boyle
>   collaborator Robert Carlyle. But Carlyle may stay uncredited,
>   according to this statement from Universal: **“The filmmakers and the
>   actor made an agreement that they would keep the actor’s identity a
>   secret out of respect for the life and memory of John Lennon. We
>   respect their wishes and therefore will not be releasing his name.”**

Also additionally from [celebretainment](https://www.celebretainment.com/movies/himesh-patel-stunned-by-shocking-yesterday-cameo/article_075f2608-fbff-5f96-b7f5-495650a3a8c4.html):

> Danny Boyle explained: "We just talked about this actor and I sent it to him. I
>   knew him, and I knew he was a lifelong Lennon fan. For him, it was a
>   special journey.
>
> **"He didn't want to be credited in the cast, in the list, and he didn't
>   want it to be talked about or become a thing or anything like that.**
>
> **"He just wanted to do it to honor someone that was very important in
>   his imaginative life.** He never met him or anything like that, but he
>   played a huge part in his imaginative life."